# Dockerfile RUN read command give me error

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, dockerfile

Good afternoon colleagues, I'm working with Docker in the construction of some images and I've found that some facilities ask the user questions such as a password.

There is the possibility of questioning the user during the process of creating the image and then passing that meter for another command, for example this code sends me an error

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
SHELL ["/bin/bash","-c"]
RUN ["echo","========== Enter root password for db =========="]
RUN ["/bin/bash","read","pass"]
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $pass"
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $pass"`
```

The error message is as follows:

`The command '/bin/bash read pass' returned to non-zero code: 127`

Then the build process fail, Any suggestion to do this, to read from user during the build time?

Comment: Why do you have spaces in your path? `/bin/bash`

Comment: Sorry there are no spaces, i just edited my code (error from copy paste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker build run in noninteractive mode - it means that it can't handle your read command to receive password from user input while building image.

I would suggest to use build args docker feature instead - see here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg
so you can read pass from user before building image and then pass it via build arg to build process but please remember that passing password using shell commands and plain text is not really safe.

Comment: hmmm i see, i thought that you can pass arguments direct from the user at build time without need to pass through the option `--build-arg`, thank you for your answer my friend.